# django - gmail shows the raw html of an email (ie the tag)

Tags: django

I'm using the django helper method send_mail, which might be the problem, but I cannot tell from the docs if that is the case.

So - here is my method:

```
send_mail('Alert!', theEmail.format(user.username),'admin@site.com',
        [user.email], fail_silently=False)
```

And theEmail looks like this:

theEmail = """





Hi {0}! 
 Here is an alert email

And here is a link: a link in time

But when i run this code, the email sends fine - but in gmail, the message is printed with all the tags visible.

Is there some sort of "send as html" thing i'm meant to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage(subject, html, from_email, [recipients])
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()
```

Comment: According to the docs: ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types ), we've to send 4 arguments while calling EmailMessage(), 3rd one being `from_email`. I don't know if it's necessary but I got an error for some reason. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with some of Django's built-in functions to escape the html string before sending (maybe gmail does some escaping/unescaping themself), e.g.:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_for_escaping
my_html = mark_for_escaping(my_raw_html)
```

or

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
my_html = mark_safe(my_raw_html)
```

`send_mail` does not support a feature like "send as html".

Comment: +1 for the string escaping, but it didn't solve the problem i had.

Answer (score 1):

Try use `html_message` argument:

```
send_mail('Alert!', '', 'admin@site.com', [user.email], html_message=theEmail.format(user.username), fail_silently=False)
```